# Protect content in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to port one of my games to WebGL, but it uses sounds and images I licensed from third parties. It would go against the license to have it just pull the unprotected files straight from the web server.

Before, I got around this by embedding a bunch of these files in my own file format, but I'm not sure if I can just read in X amount of bytes from a file and then pass it to Javascript and say "hey, this is a png image." Is that possible? Are there any other good ways to protect files?

Comment: So the licence requires.. what? That you embed the content directly into a compiled executable? If so, no matter what you do, Javascript is probably going to violate that...

Comment: The licence just requires that the files aren't out in the open where somebody could get to them easily (by just inspecting the directory or something like that).

Comment: The nature of the web means somebody will be able to get to them easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAIAAAACUFjqAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAABJJREFUeJxj+N/wHw9iGJXGhgDu6Pk5cOz+IwAAABF0RVh0Q29tbWVudAB0RVhUIHRleHTAVE3RAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
```

Then if you embed that string somewhere obscure and scramble it it should keep away the low-hanging fruit.

Comment: Chris could you revise this and provide more information? I am really interested in this. I think this is exactly what I am looking for. Where could I find more information?

Answer (score 3):

If the stuff has to end up in a user's browser, then, well, there it is in the user's browser.  You can't protect it other than by obfuscation, which is a complete waste of time if the stuff you're protecting has actual value. (Think of it this way: if it's really valuable stuff — meaning that you'd suffer some considerable loss if somebody got it illicitly, and that the thief would reap considerable gains — then the minor effort necessary to overcome obfuscation is obviously worthwhile to the thief.)

Comment: Right. Everything you see, hear or smell in your browser has already been passed to the browser and hence the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect content in your JS file you will need to create a JS durable object, by defining an object that is the result of a function call.

something like this...

```
var imageContainer = function(protectedImageContainer) {
        var that = {};
        that.getImage = function () { 
              // bytes -> image transform would happen here.
              return protectedImageContainer.data; 
        };
        return that;
};
```

In this example, protectedImageContainer.data is protected and tamper-proof, only accessible through your getImage method.

This along with blocking a right-click "Save as..." should get you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: In the "// bytes -> image" part is the idea to create a new Image() object and define its pixel data yourself, instead of doing something like new Image("path/to/img.png")?

Answer (score 0):

You can't protect stuff in javascript since it executes in the client-side and anything you do to obfuscate or "protect" the files can be undone by a user willing enough to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Would your license permit you to store the resources in encrypted form on a web server? If this is not an option then you're probably going to have to use something that can encapsulate the media -- Java Applets, perhaps.

Comment: If the user can pull the applet into the browser, then the user can save the applet and take it apart.

Comment: Can you tell Javascript to decrypt an image file after downloading it? (i.e. something like "var img = new EncryptedImage(url,key)")

Comment: @Chris: You're going down a blind alley, I'm afraid. All this obfuscation will inevitably fail. When dealing with web content, abandon all hope of "securing" it.

Comment: @Pointy - yes, that's correct but I think it's less about what a dedicated hacker can do and more about what is reasonable. After all, there really is no solution that cannot be defeated in some manner, so what's the point in even having licensable resources if the fact that they might be accessed in an unauthorized manner is a show stopper? No different than the lock and key to your front door really... they're not intended to keep people out, they're intended to require effort to bypass -- hopefully an effort that most people will not wish to exercise.

Comment: If something is worth *protecting*, it's worth *stealing*.  That's the fundamental problem. If it's not worth stealing, why bother to protect it?  If it *is* worth stealing, then it has to be really protected, and not make-believe protected.